# XSL-FO Document: Inserting a break-before="page" attribute in a concrete fo:table-row

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, xsl-fo

I have an XSL-FO document. This document has a lot of fo:table nested.
There is an inner fo:table that has 9 columns and a lot of rows, in this example, first row for table header and other rows, from 1 to 20 for content. In the example below you can see that as a comment, for each FOPTable (fo:table) it is indicated a unique identifier, but this identifier is not always the same for the same table. It is generated randomly by the application that creates this XSL-FO document.

My question is: I want to find the table which has its first column header value set to HEADER_COL1 (this value is always the same), in this example, table identified with id:997 (rember that I cannot search for table according to this identifier since it changes randomly each time application creates the XSL-FO document). Once I have found the desired table I want below:

1. How can I insert an attribute break-before="page" for a concrete
   fo:table-row item?
2. I want to get the number of rows that this inner table has.

For example:

For example, If I want to insert this attribute for the 15th fo:table-row item, how can I do this? I want a parametrized generic method that take as an argument a number indicating the fo:table-row where to put this attribute.

I know that I can read the XSL-FO document  using below:

```
string xmlFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\MyXSLFO.xml");
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlFile);
```

But once loaded i have no idea on how to do this.

**Note**: I am using Visual Studio 2008, C# and .NET 3.5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<fo:page-sequence force-page-count="no-force" master-reference="first" initial-page-number="1">
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
<!--  begin table FOPTable { id: 987 cur_size: 28.7 prv_size: 20.0 prev: <none> cols: 2 locks: 2 flow:FOPFlow: { type: BodyFlow size:4 region:FOPRegion: { type:3 extent:0.0}} } 
  --> 
<fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" space-before.optimum="0.05cm" table-layout="fixed">
</fo:table>
<!--  endof table id FOPTable { id: 987 cur_size: 28.7 prv_size: 20.0 prev: <none> cols: 2 locks: 5 flow:FOPFlow: { type: BodyFlow size:4 region:FOPRegion: { type:3 extent:0.0}} } 
  --> 
<!--  begin table FOPTable { id: 992 cur_size: 28.7 prv_size: 20.0 prev: <none> cols: 2 locks: 2 flow:FOPFlow: { type: BodyFlow size:3 region:FOPRegion: { type:3 extent:0.0}} } 
  --> 
<fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" space-before.optimum="0.05cm" table-layout="fixed">
</fo:table>
<!--  endof table id FOPTable { id: 992 cur_size: 28.7 prv_size: 20.0 prev: <none> cols: 2 locks: 4 flow:FOPFlow: { type: BodyFlow size:3 region:FOPRegion: { type:3 extent:0.0}} } 
  --> 
<!--  begin table FOPTable { id: 995 cur_size: 28.7 prv_size: 0.0 prev: <none> cols: 2 locks: 2 flow:FOPFlow: { type: BodyFlow size:2 region:FOPRegion: { type:3 extent:0.0}} } 
  --> 
<fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" space-before.optimum="0.05cm" table-layout="fixed">

<!--  begin table FOPTable { id: 996 cur_size: 0.0 prv_size: 20.41 prev: 995 cols: 1 locks: 2 flow:null } 
  --> 
<fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" table-layout="fixed">

<!--  begin table FOPTable { id: 997 cur_size: 0.0 prv_size: 20.409999999999997 prev: 996 cols: 9 locks: 5 flow:null } 
  --> 
<fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" table-layout="fixed">
  <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
  <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
  <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
  <fo:table-column column-width="4.709999999999996cm" /> 
  <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
  <fo:table-column column-width="3.9cm" /> 
  <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
  <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
  <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
<fo:table-header>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
  <fo:block>HEADER_COL1</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
  <fo:block>HEADER_COL2</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
  <fo:block>HEADER_COL3</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
  <fo:block>HEADER_COL4</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
  <fo:block>HEADER_COL5</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
  <fo:block>HEADER_COL6</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
  <fo:block>HEADER_COL7</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
  <fo:block>HEADER_COL8</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
  <fo:block>HEADER_COL9</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-header>
<fo:table-body>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW1_COL1_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW1_COL2_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW1_COL3_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW1_COL4_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW1_COL5_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW1_COL6_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-right="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block text-align="end">ROW1_COL7_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW1_COL8_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW1_COL9_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>


<!-- A LOT OF ROWS HERE -->

<!-- I want to insert a break-before attribute as below -->
<fo:table-row break-before="page">
<!-- columns here -->
</fo:table-row>

<!-- MORE ROWS HERE -->

<!-- LAST ROW NEXT -->
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW20_COL1_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW20_COL2_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW20_COL3_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW20_COL4_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW20_COL5_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW20_COL6_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-right="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block text-align="end">ROW20_COL7_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW20_COL8_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="7pt">
  <fo:block>ROW20_COL9_VALUE</fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
<!--  endof table id FOPTable { id: 997 cur_size: 28.7 prv_size: 20.409999999999997 prev: 996 cols: 9 locks: 6 flow:null } 
  --> 
</fo:table>

</fo:table>

</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: I would use XSLT. Since you're using VS2008, see https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116. You could make a template for your context that adds the attribute for the property, and make an identity template that copies the rest of the document to the result tree.

Comment: It seems overly complicated to nest tables 3 levels deep. Is this really necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your data and removing all the cells and other non-important content, one could simply apply an identity XSL to the XSL FO and modify only the target row.

starting with this XML:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <fo:page-sequence force-page-count="no-force" master-reference="first" initial-page-number="1">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" space-before.optimum="0.05cm" table-layout="fixed">
            </fo:table>
            <fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" space-before.optimum="0.05cm" table-layout="fixed">
            </fo:table>
            <fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" space-before.optimum="0.05cm" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" table-layout="fixed">
                    <fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" table-layout="fixed">
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="4.709999999999996cm" /> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="3.9cm" /> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm" /> 
                        <fo:table-header>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL1</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL2</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL3</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL4</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL5</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL6</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL7</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL8</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL9</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row/>
                            <fo:table-row/>
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:table>

            </fo:table>

        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

And applying this XSL which outputs everything as is, except for a template that inserts a page-break on the 12th row in the target table:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:param name="breakrow" select="12"/>

    <xsl:template match="fo:table-row">
        <xsl:variable name="rowcnt" select="count(preceding-sibling::fo:table-row)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="parent::fo:table-header">
                <fo:table-row>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$rowcnt = $breakrow and ancestor::fo:table[1]/fo:table-header/fo:table-row[1]/fo:table-cell[1]/fo:block/text() = 'HEADER_COL1'">
                <fo:table-row break-before="page"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:table-row/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is this:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <fo:page-sequence force-page-count="no-force" master-reference="first" initial-page-number="1">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" space-before.optimum="0.05cm" table-layout="fixed">
            </fo:table>
            <fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" space-before.optimum="0.05cm" table-layout="fixed">
            </fo:table>
            <fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" space-before.optimum="0.05cm" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" table-layout="fixed">
                    <fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" table-layout="fixed">
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm"/> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm"/> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm"/> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="4.709999999999996cm"/> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm"/> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="3.9cm"/> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm"/> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm"/> 
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2.87cm"/> 
                        <fo:table-header>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL1</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL2</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL3</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL4</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL5</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL6</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL7</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL8</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-left="2.0pt" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" border-color="#000000" background-color="#D6DEE7" font-family="sans-serif">
                                    <fo:block>HEADER_COL9</fo:block> 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row/>
                            <fo:table-row/>
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row break-before="page"/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                            <fo:table-row/>                            
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:table>

            </fo:table>

        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

I passed in 12 as a parameter and assumed that you had only one place ... the 12th row. You can certainly use "mod" and do every 12th row or whatever you desire.

Like for instance:

```
 <xsl:when test="$rowcnt mod $breakrow = $breakrow - 1 and ancestor::fo:table[1]/fo:table-header/fo:table-row[1]/fo:table-cell[1]/fo:block/text() = 'HEADER_COL1'">
```

And of course you can just add  to the rows to get all the cell content output.

Comment: Great approach, out of curiosity can I apply more <xsl:when>? for example: if $rowcnt >10 and $rowcnt <20 then apply $rowcnt = $breakrow else if  $rowcnt >=20 and $rowcnt <50 then apply $rowcnt = $AnotherBreakrow else apply $rowcnt mod $breakrow = $breakrow - 1

Comment: Of course but typically one would do what i wrote last using mod which inserts a break every  "x" rows

Comment: If the answer helped you consider marking the question appropriately.

Comment: The answer helped but can you indicate me on how to do what explained in my previous comment please?